Conflicto de versiones en un virtual environment
Tengo un proyecto para el cual creé un venv cuya version de python era 3.11.8, pero luego de hacer una actualización de mi sistema (arch linux), mi versión de python paso a ser 3.12.3, lo cual tambien cambió la versión de python de mis virtual environments, para volver a la versión anterior de python instalé pyenv y luego instalé la versión 3.11.8 haciendo que fuera la versión global del sistema, pero luego de activar el venv y consultar por la versión de python me di cuenta que la versión de este aún era 3.12.3, hay alguna forma de cambiar la versión de este virtual environment o debo crearlo desde cero?
Contenido del pyenv.cfg:
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11.8
executable = /usr/bin/python3.11
command = /usr/bin/python -m venv /home/pincheira/Projects/proyecto_ibn/backend/env


Tu pyenv.cfg debería ser:
home = /home/pincheira/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11.8
executable = /home/pincheira/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/bin/python3.11
command = /home/pincheira/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/bin/python -m venv /home/pincheira/Projects/proyecto_ibn/backend/env

El problema es que tu venv está asociado al intérprete del sistema. El interprete en tu venv en realidad es un mero enlace simbólico a éste (a /usr/bin/python). Por lo tanto es imprescindible que modifiques el destino de /home/pincheira/Projects/proyecto_ibn/backend/env/bin/python a /home/pincheira/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/bin/python:
ln -vfns /home/pincheira/.pyenv/versions/3.11.8/bin/python /home/pincheira/Projects/proyecto_ibn/backend/env/bin/python

Si no has instalado nada en el VENV desde que actualizaste el interprete del sistema debería funcionar, en principio.
Comprueba que las rutas al intérprete de pyenv y de tu venv sean correctas, las he deducido de tu .cfg y de las rutas de instalación por defecto de pyenv.
